# Django - image not upload

Tags: django, python-3.x

On the site already have some queries related to this, but none of them solved my problem in fact.
I have a table without a database with a user table, with a table of my image that shows the image of the user profile.

Models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user   = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.first_name)
```

Views.py

```
@login_required()
def editaFoto(request, id):
    data = {}
    foto = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=id)
    form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance = foto) # inicia um formulario com os campos preenchidos
    data['foto'] = foto
    data['form'] = form

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('lista_perfil')
    else:
        return render(request, 'sistema/perfil/editafoto.html', data)
```

forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
```

Editafoto.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load bootstrap %}

{% block title %}
    Editar Foto
{% endblock title %}

{% block main %}    
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Editar Foto</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {{ foto }}
                <form action="{% url 'edita_foto' user.id %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form | bootstrap}}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
                    <a href="{% url 'lista_perfil' %}" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock main %}
```

Base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="icon" type="imagem/png" href="{% static 'img/icone.jpg' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/menu.css' %}">
    {% block scripts %} {% endblock scripts %}
    {% block style %} {% endblock style %}
    <title>{% block title %}  {% endblock title %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark" style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sistema</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'lista_consultas' %}">Consultas<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'lista_medicos' %}">Medicos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'lista_pacientes' %}">Pacientes</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'lista_especialidades' %}">Especialidades</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'cadastra_usuario' %}">Usuários</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                {% if user.userprofile.avatar == "" %}
                    <img src="{% static 'img/user-anonimo-clinica.jpg' %}" style="border-radius: 100%; margin-top: .5rem;" width="30" height="30" alt="user">
                {% else %}
                    <img src="{{ user.userprofile.avatar.url }}" style="border-radius: 100%; margin-top: .5rem;" width="30" height="30" alt="user">
                {% endif %}
                <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            {{user}}
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-perfil">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'lista_perfil' %}">Meu Perfil</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </li>
            </ul>
                <!--
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="">Olá {{user}}</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}-->

        </div>
    </nav>

    <div style="margin-bottom: 40px">
        {% block main %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <footer class="footer " style="height:20px;width: 100%; background-color:#000; position: fixed; margin:auto; bottom:0">

    </footer>
</body>
```

This my current code works great when I use Django admin. If I enter Django admin and add an image to a user, the image appears on the system normally.

But I wanted to add the user profile image to my system, but when I go to the editafoto.html page and give a submit, it does not save the new image in the database, no error appears, it simply does not save and does not nothing happens

Could someone show me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting to add `request.FILES` to your code.

```
UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=foto)
```

also, make sure you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` tag.

```
<form action="{% url 'edita_foto' user.id %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Did you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` tag?